# How to use Methods in SqLite Linq Query?

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, windows-store-apps

I want use the Tolower string function in linq query, but when the app is running, the lnq search the function in sqlite.

Error:

> Additional information: no such function: tolower

Code:

```
 var data = conn.Table<_table>().Where(x=> x.name.ToLower() == param).ToList();
```

How can i use non sqlite functions in linq query ?

**Thx for any help !**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to make the column you're doing the comparison on case insensitive.  Then you would no longer need to use `ToLower` to compare your strings since it is ultimately translating your linq to a sql statement.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
(
    name text collate nocase
);
```

Comment: thx,I was looking for different solutions, but i didn't find other.